# When creating a database - Is it advisable to create a column for data I can calculate based on other fields?

Tags: database, field

I am building an application for a lawyer, in which he can create a client portfolio. In this portfolio, there is the ID of the portfolio, the creation date, the client's name, telephone, etc.

Besides of all these fields, there is another field: "portfolio name". This field contains some information about the client from the other fields, in a formatted text.

So, for example, if:

1. **ID** = *271*
2. **client_name** = "*John Doe*"
3. **creation_date** = *18/02/2016*

the **portfolio_name** will be *271/John Doe/18022016*.

Now, since the **portifolio_name** is not really containing new data, but only formatted data from other fields, should it really exist in the database table as a column? Is that *Data Duplication* or not?

Comment: It is data duplication, but a level or redundancy can be acceptable in certain instances.

Comment: Depends. At the very least I would make it an actual calculated column in the table if your DB supports that. If he changes to a different format which can't be calculated, you'll have a lot of reworking to do.

Comment: Could you please reply in an answer? So other people could benefit more easily from your answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a textbook violation of 1NF and should generally be avoided. It's acceptable in some cases -- for example, where the calculated value is very difficult or time-consuming to obtain. However, since string concatenation is so simple (you can even do it right in your query, without the definition of any pseudo-fields) I wouldn't ever recommend doing this unless the field simply contains an initial default value and the client has the ability to customize it later. Otherwise, it *will* eventually become inconsistent. E.g., what happens when a client's name changes?

Comment: SQL computed columns solve this without breaking 1NF.

Comment: Sure, that's a viable solution, assuming your database supports them. However, note that computed columns are not standard SQL, so you're introducing a dependency on a specific database engine for nothing more than simple string concatenation. In addition, the calculation would be considered business logic, and as it would be built into your schema instead of your application code, it would not be (easily) source controlled should it change.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the table and how you query the table.

If the table is large you can create a column for the calculated field. So that it will be easy for querying.

If the table small you can calculate in the query

Comment: It's a big table, I think. Thousands of records... But isn't that bad to make data duplication even if it complicates the query a little bit?

Comment: Thousands of records is not big. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most database engines allow you to create a computed column for this exact purpose.  Depending on the engine and how you set up the computed column it may or may not be saved to disk, but it will be guaranteed to be always up to date.  The nice thing is that you can treat it like it's a read only column.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx